# What is the largest winning margin, in seconds, in an F1 race?

Tags: formula-1

In an F1 race, when the leader dominates a particular track, the gap between the winner and 2nd place can be really long in terms of seconds. What is the largest gap, in seconds, between the winner and the runner-up in an F1 race? Was there ever a race where the 2nd-placed driver was lapped by the winner?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the largest gap, in seconds, between the winner and the runner-up in an F1 race?

That would be the [1958 Portuguese Grand Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1958_Portuguese_Grand_Prix), held at the 7.4 km-long Circuito de Boavista. Stirling Moss beat championship rival Mike Hawthorn by **5 minutes, 12.75 seconds**. Incidentally, this was also the race at which Hawthorn was initially disqualified until Moss protested on his behalf, a gesture which ultimately allowed Hawthorn to beat Moss to the title that year (and prevented Moss' record winning margin from being even larger).

> Was there ever a race where the 2nd-placed driver was lapped by the winner?

Yes. There have, in fact, been two races where the 2nd-place driver was lapped *twice* by the winner. The first was the [1969 Spanish Grand Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1969_Spanish_Grand_Prix), with Jackie Stewart finishing two laps ahead of Bruce McLaren in 2nd. The second was the [1995 Australian Grand Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1995_Australian_Grand_Prix), where Damon Hill was the only frontrunner not to suffer technical issues; Olivier Panis in 2nd suffered an oil leak in the closing stages that allowed Hill to lap him for a second time.